# Docker-compose error when try to start

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am having a funny error when I try to run a docker-compose. I have reinstall the VM several times, everything is update and install but I cannot run a compose.

```
$ sudo docker-compose up -d
Creating network "apache2_default" with the default driver
Building mysql
ERROR: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): permission denied
```

My docker-composer.yml file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql:
    build: ./mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
  php:
    build: ./php
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - ./html:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - mysql
volumes:
  db:
```

I have run this in Mac and it works

Edit:

Dockerfile fot mysql:

```
FROM mysql:5.7
COPY ./my.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: maybe show us the dockerfile if any and the yml file

Comment: The build of your `mysql` service is failing. Please provide the corresponding `Dockerfile`

Comment: What OS is the VM? What version of Docker? How are you copying the `docker-compose.yml` file and code to the VM? In the VM, can you list the files and their permissions?

Answer (score 0):

The `docker build` build command can fail with permission error when there are files (or folders) in the build context directory which aren't owned by the current user.

This situation happens when you mount a volume to a host directory ; the files in that directory might be owned by root.

The fix is quite easy: just create a `.dockerignore` file with the name of the directories/files you don't own and don't require in the docker image build.

---

For instance:

```
docker run -d -v $(pwd)/data-volume:/var/lib/mysql mysql
```

would create a `data-volume` directory.

If you were to build a Dockerfile, you would have the following content in your `.dockerignore`:

> ```
> data-volume
> ```